# Format Specifiers in C

Tags: c, floating-point

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("%d %f ", 4.0, 4.0);
    getch();
}
```

I am getting output as `0 4.000000`. I want to know the accurate reason.

Comment: Usage of the incorrect format specifier is an undefined behavior. You could get any result, depending on the compiler/c standard library implementation.

Comment: Using `conio.h` and missing to specify a return value for `main` seem to indicate that you are using a pre-historic C compiler. There are good open  source compilers around for all modern platforms that are uptodate with modern standards, you should definitively switch to one of those.

Comment: Another 'explain UB for me' question.  DCV:.  'I want to know the accurate reason' AKA 'My prof/TA wants me to write the accurate reason':(

Comment: sorry but am not satisfied with your reason !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the output is due to undefined behavior (UB).  UB has no specification, thus an _accurate_ answers is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason is because you are using wrongly the Format Specifiers...

When you do this:

```
printf("%d %f ",4.0,4.0f);
```

you are telling your compiler that you are printing an **integer** and a **float**, you are passing 2 floating points instead, so the compiler is not abel to cast the float to int

do instad

```
printf("%d %f ",(int)4.0,4.0f);
```

---

more reference about Format Specifiers..

**Usual variable type           Display**

**%c        char                     single character**

**%d (%i)   int                      signed integer**

**%e (%E)   float or double          exponential format**

**%f        float**

**%lf double**

**%g (%G)   float or double          use %f or %e as required**

**%o        int                      unsigned octal value**

**%p        pointer                  address stored in pointer**

**%s        array of char            sequence of characters**

**%u        int                      unsigned decimal**

**%x (%X)   int                      unsigned hex value**

Comment: `%f` is for `double`, `float` get converted to `double` when passed to variadic function `printf`.  `%lf` is the same as `%f`, the `l` is ignored. `%p` requires a `void *` pointer.

Comment: Shouldn't the compiler implicitly cast 4.0 to int?

Comment: @Claudio Cortese  No, the compiler need not implicitly cast 4.0 to an `int`.  The C spec specifically says such a format/argument mis-match is undefined behavior (UB).  A compiler _could_ perform a cast (I know of none that do).  Many compilers will _detect_ the issue and give a warning.

Comment: no no am  question is why 4.0 get converted to 0.000000 as %d here is used  instead of 4 as a answer

Comment: @NAVJOTSINGH It was misinterpreted because `%d` requires an integer argument and 4.0 is not an integer. It does not get converted to an integer because `printf` doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 0):

The `printf` function doesn't know what type of data to expect in the variable arguments list unless you tell it what's there.  That's what data type part of the format specifier is for.

What's happening for you is you told it that the first argument is a `int`, but then you gave it a different data type.  The result is undefined.

If you want to see the type of thing that `printf` is doing under the hood, then read up on [variadic functions in C](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic).  That will give you a better idea of why it's so important for the type the function expects to be the same type you gave it.

To offer a code example taken from the link I just provided:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void simple_printf(const char* fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);

    while (*fmt != '\0') {
        if (*fmt == 'd') {
            int i = va_arg(args, int);
            printf("%d\n", i);
        } else if (*fmt == 'c') {
            // note automatic conversion to integral type
            int c = va_arg(args, int);
            printf("%c\n", c);
        } else if (*fmt == 'f') {
            double d = va_arg(args, double);
            printf("%f\n", d);
        }
        ++fmt;
    }

    va_end(args);
}

int main(void)
{
    simple_printf("dcff", 3, 'a', 1.999, 42.5); 
}
```